# Почему возвращает 0 записей php ldap?

Tags: php, ldap

подскажите, почему при таком подключении выдает 0 записей, хотя на сервере есть записи

```
$LDAP = array(
'server' => '217.107.193.59',
'port' => '389',
'user' => 'ldapadmin@test.epc.local',
'pass' => '123$zxc',
'dn' => 'OU=epc,DC=epc,DC=local'
);
// Подключаемся к серверу
$adconn = ldap_connect($LDAP['server'], $LDAP['port'])
    or die('Не могу подключиться к LDAP-серверу 1');

// Устанавливаем версию протокола 
ldap_set_option($adconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

// Привязка
ldap_bind($adconn, $LDAP['user'], $LDAP['pass'])
or die('Не мего подключиться к LDAP серверу 11');

// выборка
$filter = "(sn=*)";
$att = array( "ou","userPrincipalName");

$result=ldap_search($adconn, $LDAP['dn'], $filter, $att);
if ($result) {
    $info = ldap_get_entries($adconn, $result);
    print $info["count"]." entries returned";
} else
    print "LDAP search error ".ldap_errno($adconn)." (".ldap_error($adconn).")";

ldap_close($adconn);
```

вот список пользователей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потомучто " Не мего "  =)

Comment: ? не понял к чему это